EPUB3 metadata: creator vs contributor
EPUB3 standard states that

The dc:contributor element [dcterms] is used to represent the name of a person, organization, etc. that played a secondary role in the creation of the content.

Then, both dc:creator and dc:contributor allow roles, e.g. expressed by MARC Relator terms (see for example here).
Is a translator a dc:creator or dc:contributor? And what about the author of a preface? Is there any reference text or best practice about such classification?

I don’t have any reference for my holding here (much less an authoritative one), but I would place both as dc:contributors:

the preface is secondary to the core work (the core work would still be there and meaningful even without the preface)
the translation wouldn't have happened if the original work hadn't .

